# Plotting live graphs on web page

Tags: html, charts, html5-canvas

I have a csv file which is appended with new data every minute, I want the data in this file to be plotted as graphs on a webpage. The csv file has 12 parmeters and I want to plot a chart of parameter vs Time.

Answer (score 1):

you can load csv data with php - more on that [here at w3school.com (fgetcsv)](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp), then you can go with canvas.context functions, you just need to create your chart with points (context.fillRect or arc for circle, or whatever shape you create with your own function) and some lines as axes.

Then you'll need something as setInterval or requestAnimationFrame to repeat this process on client side periodically.

Otherwise, you can find a lot about html5 charts if you just google it, there are libraries which are made especially for these cases, and a lot of tutorials as well.

I'm not too sure what exactly are you looking for here from your question though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like @VicoLemp has your data loading process covered.

Here's a simple line chart on canvas for you to start with.

Feel free to style it to fit your design needs:

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var PI2=Math.PI*2;
var offsetX=20;
var offsetY=20;

var points=randomData(12);

plotData(points,250,250);

function plotData(pts,chartWidth,chartHeight){

  var range=calcSourceMinMax(pts);

  var p=[];
  for(var i=0;i<pts.length;i++){
    var mappedX=mapRange(i,0,pts.length,0,chartWidth)+offsetX;
    var mappedY=ch-(mapRange(pts[i],range.min,range.max,0,chartHeight)+offsetY);
    p.push({x:mappedX,y:mappedY});
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p[0].x,p[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<p.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(p[i].x,p[i].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();

  for(var i=0;i<p.length;i++){
    var pt=p[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pt.x,pt.y,3,0,PI2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillText(i,pt.x,pt.y-5);
    ctx.fillText(i+' = '+pts[i],chartWidth+offsetX+20,i*15);
  }

}



////////////////////////////
// Utilities

//
function mapRange(value, sourceLow, sourceHigh, mappedLow, mappedHigh) {
  return mappedLow + (mappedHigh - mappedLow) * (value - sourceLow) / (sourceHigh - sourceLow);
}

//
function calcSourceMinMax(a){
  var min=1000000;
  var max=-1000000;
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    var value=a[i];
    if(value<min){min=value;}
    if(value>max){max=value;}
  }
  return({min:min,max:max});
}

//
function randomData(count){
  var a=[];
  for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    a.push(parseInt(Math.random()*100));
  }
  return(a);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
```